# Register events for old date in Mixpanel

Tags: javascript, node.js, mixpanel

We have a database with old data, and I would like to see mixpanel reports of these data. Server-side I can insert this data in mixpanel, but they will all be tracked as if they happened today. Is it possible to insert events in mixpanel changing the date they happened (e.g. inserting an event as if it has happened yesterday) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I've found different ways to perform this operations. To register events for an old date, you must import these events. There is an [endpoint](https://developer.mixpanel.com/docs/importing-old-events) if you want to do that by HTTP, or you can use one of the mixpanel API's. [mixpanel-api](https://github.com/mixpanel/mixpanel_api) for python can also be used to deduplicate profiles.